# Unable to drop table in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've been trying everything literally, the table exists but i just can't seem to be able to drop it.
table is named 'student'.

**DDL:**

```
drop table student cascade constraints; 
drop table student;
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Find the schema name using the data dictionary : all_tables  . And use the schema name/owner as a prefix to delete the table.

```
Select owner, TABLE_NAME from all_tables where table_name = 'STUDENT' 

Drop table <owner>.<table_name>   -- replace <owner> and <table_name> with proper values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are connected to the right database.  Other possibilities are that there are foreign keys to student.  Check other table creation scripts to make sure that there are no lines like:

```
studentId References student(id)
```

Comment: No references whatsoever. Zero foreign keys, I only have one table which is 'student', the one I'm unable to drop.

Comment: From your error message you quoted in your question, it looks like you already dropped the table.

Comment: It still shows up when I run select * from cat. the table is still there.

Comment: What about select * from student?

Comment: It could be that the user you are logged in with has not been granted select access